# Confusion in finding derivative of $\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{1 + \cos(2x)}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry, solution-verification

> Find $f'(x)$ where $f(x) = \sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos(2x)}{1 + \cos(2x)}}$.

This question is given in my textbook but I don't agree with the solution given in my book and various sites on the internet.

---

**The book shows the following method:**

$$f(x) = \sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos(2x)}{1 + \cos(2x)}} =\sqrt{\dfrac{2\sin^2(x)}{2\cos^2(x)}}=\sqrt{\tan^2x}= \tan(x)$$
So the derivative of $\tan(x)$ is $\sec^2(x).$

---

But my confusion is that, $\sqrt{\tan^2(x)}$ should be $|\tan(x)|$ and so, it's derivative cannot be equal to $\sec^2x$.

Derivative of $|x|$ is $\dfrac{x}{|x|}$.

So, the derivative of $|\tan(x)|$ should be $\dfrac{\tan(x) \cdot \sec^2(x)}{|\tan(x)|}.\bf\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad....(1)$

Or we can also say that derivative of $|\tan(x)|= \begin{cases}\sec^2{x},\rm If\, tan(x)\ge0\\-\sec^2x, \rm If \tan(x) < 0 \end{cases}.\bf\qquad....(2)$

Am, I right in **(1)** and **(2)**?

Comment: Although I agree with you, one should be careful about the domain of definition of functions - when you write the derivative of $\vert x\vert$, it is not define if $x=0$

Comment: [More concisely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function), $f^\prime(x)=\operatorname{sgn}(\tan x)\sec^2x$.

Comment: +1 for finding an error in a textbook.

Comment: Using the function floor the derivative can be written as $f'(x)= (-1)^{\lfloor 2 x/\pi\rfloor }\frac{1}{\cos(x)^2}$

Comment: The function is even, hence its derivative (for $x\neq 0$) is an odd function. Therefore the textbook answer is certainly wrong.

Comment: f(x) is not defined where cos 2x = -1. For any other x, f(x) is the square root of a number >= 0, divided by a number > 0, so well defined. But clearly for example f(-0.1) ≠ tan (-0.1).

Comment: $$f’(x) = \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos 2x }{1 - \cos 2x}} \tan x\sec^2x$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are absolutely correct.
The function is equal to $|\tan(x)|$.
You can also plot the given function in desmos. There is a sharp edge at $x=0$ and the function is not differentiable at $x=0$.
$$
f'(x)= \begin{cases}\hspace{10 pt} \sec^2{x},& \text{if }\, \tan(x)>0,\\-\sec^2x,& \text{if }\, \tan(x) < 0. \end{cases}\bf\qquad
$$

[image: Graph]

Comment: Continuity does not implies differentiability. However for a function to be differentiable a point continuity is necessary. Differentiability implies continuity and smoothness. A function having sharp edge at a point implies left hand derivative and right hand derivative are not equal hence the function is not differentiable at that point.

Comment: If a function is not continuous at a point then It cannot be differentiable at that point. But If it is continuous then It may or may not be differentiable provided If it has a sharp edge at that point or not.

Answer (score 0):

Both your formulations in (1) and (2) are correct, and we do indeed require the absolute value for this.

The answer of $f'(x)=\sec^2x$ is clearly incorrect as $f(x)≠\tan x,$ but rather $$f(x)=\frac{\mid\sin x\mid}{\mid \cos x\mid}= {\mid\tan x\mid}$$

If we differentiate this then we see that you are definitely correct with **(1)**

Your answer in **(2)** is also correct and we can see $f(x)$ [red] and $f'(x)$ [purple] graphically

[image]

This makes the "piecewise" nature of $f'(x)$ clear as it is equal to $+\sec^2 x$ only for $\tan x>0$

Answer (score 0):

There is another to prove that you are correct.

Use the logarithmic differentiation
$$f(x) = \sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos(2x)}{1 + \cos(2x)}} \implies \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\csc (x) \sec (x)$$

Comment: @Anonymous. Don't you see the discontinuity at $x=0$ because of $\csc(x)$ ?

Comment: @Anonymous Take logarithm of  both sides: $\ln(f(x))=\frac12(\ln(1-\cos(2x))-\ln(1+\cos(2x)))$. Now take derivative.