# Why do we take $\sqrt{f^2(x)} = f(x)$ when integrating by substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration, absolute-value, substitution

I've posted a similar question [Confusion in finding derivative of $\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{1 + \cos(2x)}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4391451/confusion-in-finding-derivative-of-sqrt-frac1-cos2x1-cos2x).

---

Consider the following integral: $$\int\sqrt{1 - x^2}\ dx.$$
Putting $x = \sin(\theta):$
$$=\int\sqrt{1 - \sin^2\theta}\ \cos\theta\ d\theta$$
$$=\int\sqrt{\cos^2\theta}\ \cos\theta\ d\theta\tag{1}$$
$$=\int\ \cos\theta\cos\theta\ d\theta\tag{2}$$
$$=\int\cos^2\theta\ d\theta$$
$$...$$
$$...$$
$$...$$

---

From step $(1)$ to $(2)$, I don't understand why we take $\sqrt{f^2(x)} = f(x)$ instead of $\sqrt{f^2(x)} =|f(x)|.$ I've seen many such examples like the above, where we ignore the negative values (mainly in substitutions in integration, differentiation, and inverse trigonometric functions).

Comment: You can write $\sqrt{f^2(x)} = f(x)$ only when you know beforehand that $f (x)\geq 0$.

Comment: Ohh so that means whenever we use the substitution method, we assume that $f(x)$ is positive? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: The line tagged (2) in your posting is **not** implied by the line tagged (1), for the very reason behind the comment of @KaviRamaMurthy.

Comment: No, it means that when you use the substitution method, new students are often careless.

Comment: @user2661923 Is it implied by the substitution "Putting $x = \sin(\theta)$"?

Comment: @Yooo No, it isn't.  You are invalidly assuming that when $\theta$ is chosen, that $\cos(\theta) \geq 0.$

Comment: @Yooo If instead, you specified that $x = \sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta) \geq 0$, or you had a specific range of integration, then that would be potentially different.  But as the posting stands, the assumption is not valid.

Comment: I think the following link https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution it's useful, see the examples @Yooo

Comment: @Yooo There are a variety of valid ways of handling it.  That is one way.  Another is to specify that $\theta$ is restricted to a specific range (i.e. $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$ or $-\pi/2 \leq \theta < \pi/2$).  An alternative way of handling it is  to make no specification as to the sign of $\cos(\theta)$, and instead, deduce that $~\displaystyle \sqrt{\cos^2(\theta)} = |\cos(\theta)|.$

Comment: @Yooo Another valid alternative, is to define something called the sign function for non-zero real numbers $x$, where $~\displaystyle \text{sign}(x) = \frac{|x|}{x},~$ which will compute to either $+1$ or $-1$.  Then, for $\cos(\theta) \neq 0$, you could infer that $~\displaystyle \sqrt{\cos^2(\theta)} = \cos(\theta) \times \text{sign}[\cos(\theta)].$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$\int\sqrt{1 - x^2}\,\mathrm dx.$$
> Putting $x = \sin(\theta):$
> \begin{align}&\implies\int\sqrt{\cos^2\theta}\ \cos\theta\,\mathrm d\theta\tag{1}\\
> &\implies\int\ \cos\theta\cos\theta\,\mathrm d\theta\tag{2}\\
> &\implies\int\cos^2\theta\,\mathrm  d\theta\end{align}
> why we take $\sqrt{f^2(x)} = f(x)$ instead of $\sqrt{f^2(x)} =|f(x)|.$

1. The above is an [implicit
   substitution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4370337/21813) of the
   form $x=h(\theta),$ which
   [requires](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2518470/21813) $h$ to be
   invertible.

   The author has tacitly restricted $\sin\theta$ to its principal
   domain so that $h$ has domain $$\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right].$$

   Thus, $\cos\theta\ge0;$ so, $\sqrt{\cos^2\theta}=|\cos\theta|$
   simply equals $\cos\theta.$
2. A nitpick: the implication symbol $\implies$ connects *statements*
   like $x^2+3x=7,$ and is not interchangeable with the symbol $=,$
   which connects *expressions* like $x^2+3x.$
3. As a contrast, this solution opts for the alternative substitution
   $\displaystyle
   x=\sin\alpha\quad\left(\alpha\in\left[\frac\pi2,\frac{3\pi}2\right]\right):$
   \begin{align}&\int\sqrt{1 - x^2}\, \mathrm dx\\
   \\={}&\int\sqrt{\cos^2\alpha}\ \cos\alpha\, \mathrm d\alpha\\
   \\= {}&\int\ (-\cos\alpha)\cos\alpha\, \mathrm d\alpha\\
   \\= {}&\int(-\cos^2\alpha)\, \mathrm d\alpha.\end{align} It nonetheless gives the same answer (the negative sign appears as this substitution function is decreasing, which flips the integration limits relative to the previous substitution): \begin{align}&\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{1 - x^2}\, \mathrm dx
   \\= {}&\int_{\color{red}{3\pi/2}}^{\color{red}{\pi/2}}(\color{red}-\cos^2\ \color{red}{ \alpha})\, \mathrm d \color{red}{\alpha}
   \\= {}&\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\cos^2\alpha\, \mathrm d\alpha \\= {}&\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\cos^2\theta\, \mathrm d\theta.\end{align}

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping me with my silly question, Sir!  :-)

Comment: It's not a silly question!

Comment: Btw what's the problem with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4391451)? It's not a substitution. And my book always assumes $\sqrt{f^2(x)} = f(x)$.

Comment: In the future, do avoid making question edits that render answers less meaningful. I nitpicked about the implication symbol because I noticed the same in one of your previous posts. Let me take a look...

Comment: There isn't a problem there: I agree with your analysis (except for the careless suggestion that the function is differentiable at $0)$ and with the accepted answer.

Comment: Ohh... Thanks for checking! Actually, I don't have any good teacher who could teach me these tiny mistakes. They simply say "It's a typo" and I unwillingly have to accept that without understanding.

Comment: Anyhow, when dealing with nonnegative functions, it isn't wrong to assert that $\sqrt{f^2(x)} \equiv f(x).$